# Monthly income section

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, proof-provenance-of-funds

While applying for a UK visit visa, is it fine to show monthly income higher than the income stated in the tax returns documents?

Comment: why does your claimed monthly income not match your tax statements?

Comment: because in our country people have a mind set that taxable income is always shown less and the monthly income is much greater than what we mention in our legal documents. people are always of a view point that if you will write less income you will never get visa for UK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the income exempt from tax and could you prove that? If you look like you are evading taxes then you demonstrate a disrespect for the law. One might reasonably conclude you won't respect the terms of your visa either.

Comment: Is it necessary to submit the Tax Return Papers while applying for UK Visit Visa? If i state that my monthly income is PKR 700000 and I do not submit my tax returns whereas my bank statement shows transactions that i am earning this much amount. would this be sufficient evidence?

Comment: @Marium the idea is to show that your income is genuinely your money and not borrowed to make you look wealthy to get a visa. Also that it is from a legitimate source and not from illegal activity. It is normal to use tax records as proof. Could you pay your taxes in full for some time and then apply for the visa when your tax and income records match?

Comment: Thankyou for replying. Actually people are suggesting us not to submit Tax return papers and just to write income and submit bank statements with it. They say that it is enough to prove that the transactions are being made into your account. So, i really need to know that if i don't submit the tax returns paper, won't there be a question that i need to prove that I am really earning this much amount?

Comment: @Marium do you have other evidence that the money is yours and legitimate such as letters from your employer?

Comment: We own our business. and we have documents from Federal Board of Revenue stating that our business in Registered with them. But that document does not state that how much monthly income we are generating from the business.

Comment: @Marium if you know someone who successfully applied for a visa without using tax records please ask them what they used instead, and please post the answer here to help other site users.

Comment: @Marium: You seem to have an inverted idea of the application process. Visa are not a right, that is why they are _granted_. To be granted a visa, you have to _convince_ the  embassy. So the question isn't which documents are necessary, but which documents are useful. Tax records and bank statements both are very useful.